# Self-updating WPF application, launcher process load WPF app via reflection

Tags: c#, wpf, launcher

In a Winforms application, we have developed a self updating application launcher and I'm trying to mimic the same with WPF but am facing some issues. The way this worked with Winforms:

- Launcher process (with not reference to main application) will check for newer libraries and download as necessary
- Launcher will then load the assembly (Assembly.Load) from an STA Thread and then via reflection, call an Init method in that assembly (that performs a bunch of init logic while the launcher is acting as a splash screen and displaying progress)

  - After Init is complete, Laucher will call a Handoff method via reflection in the loaded assembly which will create a new ApplicationContext with the new MainForm and then call Application.Run(newAppContext).
  - Launcher will close its Window

I'm trying to mimic the same in WPF but the issues I'm having:

- There doesn't appear to be the concept of ApplicationContext that I could transfer the MainForm to
- I'm not sure how to handle App.xaml/resources since I can't put a "second" App.xaml in the application dll, so I'm not sure how to handle loading of resources/styles
- When I Show a new MainWindow in the "Handoff" call that is called via reflection, the window opens briefly but then disappears

Appreciate any guidance on how I can implement the desired behavior in a Wpf application.

Comment: Why not just use _ClickOnce_?  Job done. In any event, any code to show?

Comment: Aside from ClickOne, the way I've done it before which is easier than what you are proposing, is just make a separate app for updating. Let your app check, `Process.Start` your updater, close app, updater does stuff, and relaunches your app. This is fairly simple, straight-forward, and gets around not being able overwrite an .exe or .dll that's running/being used.

Comment: System.Windows.Application.Run(mainWindow), this is an instance method

Comment: I got to ask, why not launch it as a normal executable with Process.Start and give it commandline parameters for the handoff? Your other option is using one of AppDomain ExecuteAssembly functions.

Comment: @JoelLucsy see: Launcher will then load the assembly (Assembly.Load) from an STA Thread and then via reflection, call an Init method in that assembly (that performs a bunch of init logic while the launcher is acting as a splash screen and displaying progress) - the launcher queries the loaded assembly and receives status updates while it is initializing, therefore Process.Start will not work

Comment: @TJF I use IPC for status updates.

Comment: @JoelLucsy - the launcher does other things like pre-jit the loaded assemblies in the current app domain, etc. - This has been working great with Winforms and does exactly what I need it to, I'm just trying to replicate the same thing with WPF and not invent any new process to accomplishing the same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interesting, solving this was actually quite trivial:

- Create a Wpf Application (the launcher)
- Create an "Application" assembly (can be a dll) that hosts the entry point for your application specific code
- Have the launcher load the application assembly dynamically (Assembly.Load)
- In your application assembly, have some static entry point that can be called via reflection from the launcher.
- When the launcher calls the entry point method via reflection, add your resources and new a MainWindow from the application assembly to assign to Application.Current.MainWindow:

  ```
     Application.Current.Resources = new ResourceDictionary() {Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/MyApp.UI.Styling;component/Common.xaml")};
     Application.Current.MainWindow = new MainWindow();
     Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();
  ```
- Back in the Launcher, Close() the Launcher window

Answer (score 0):

WPF apps derive from a base class of System.Windows.Application. The basic template that VS uses creates a App.xaml and App.xaml.cs. This class has an static entry point of

```
public static void Main()
```

This is what I use:

```
var type = yourloadedassembly.GetType( "YourNamespace.App" );
type.InvokeMember( "Main", BindingFlags::Public | BindingFlags::Static | BindingFlags::InvokeMethod, null, null, null );
```

Comment: When I try that I'm getting: InvalidOperationException: Cannot create more than one System.Windows.Application instance in the same AppDomain.

Comment: Is your updater a WPF app? if so, you might need to run it from a separate AppDomain. WPF likes to be in its own space.

Comment: It is, yes - I'm trying that but still getting the same error, not sure what I'm doing wrong:

 var domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("test", null, new AppDomainSetup {ApplicationBase = Environment.CurrentDirectory});
 var asm = domain.Load("MyApp);
  var types = asm.GetTypes();
... get my type
 type.InvokeMember("Main", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, null, null);

Comment: And if I try to call directly on the AppDomain:

 domain.DoCallBack(() => type.InvokeMember("Main", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, null, null));

I get: System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: 'Type 'StartUpManager+<>c__DisplayClass9_0' in assembly 'Launcher, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable.'

Comment: AppDomains are very picky. Entirely too easy to get  the assembly loaded into your own domain. I suspect when you get the types through asm.GetTypes(), you're actually loading that assembly into your current domain and it is trying to run it from there. My expertise in AppDomains is lacking. I do know any class you call needs to be Serializable to be able to cross the domain boundry, and I had used CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap to get that class across and call functions on it.

Comment: Thanks and I think therein lies the rub. If I load it into a separate AppDomain, I won't be able to use reflection since calling between the two domains uses remoting and I can't use reflection with that. Since the Launcher has no reference to the app, I won't be able to CreateInstanceAndUnwrap. Possibly could introduce a 3rd assembly with a type that is referenced by the launcher and holds a reference to the app to perform init and call CreateInstanceAndUnwrap on that. I still think there's probably a way to do this via reflection and loading resources from app assembly in Application.Current

Comment: Yeah, i remember having to use a another assembly to do work in the other AppDomain. I'm afraid I can't be of more help beyond this point without actually sitting down and trying to figure it out myself.